# Add adjacent post function inside custom recent post function

Tags: wp-query

I have a function that shows the recent three (3) blog posts side by side. Now I want to add arrows (next, prev) below recent post columns that slide more posts. Is that possible with `get_adjacent_post` function, and is there any example of how I can implement that to this function?

```
function RecentPosts() {
    $rPosts = new WP_Query();
    $rPosts->query('showposts=3');

        while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'small-thumb' ); ?>
        <?php $image_url = $image[0]; ?>

        <div class="recentPost">
          <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="third-box">
                <h3 class="recentPostTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p class="recentPostBody"><?php echo trimResult(wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content()), '100'); ?></p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
};

add_shortcode('recentposts', 'RecentPosts');
```